# Hanging else problem?

Tags: c++, pascal

What is the "hanging else" problem? (Is that the right name?)

Following a C++ coding standard (forgot which one) I always
use brackets (block) with control structures. So I don't
normally have this problem (to which "if" does the last(?)
else belong), but for understanding possible problems in
foreign code it would be nice with a firm understanding of
this problem. I remember reading about it in a book about
Pascal many years ago, but I can't find that book.

Comment: I believe it would be the "dangling else" problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Which `if` does the `else` belong to?

```
if (a < b)
    if (c < d)
        a = b + d;
    else
        b = a + c;
```

(Obviously you should ignore the indentation.)

That's the "hanging else problem".

C/C++ gets rid of the ambiguity by having a rule that says you can't have an-`if`-without-an-`else` as the `if`-body of an-`if`-with-an-`else`.

Comment: I never understood the problem, to be honest. I am inexperienced in the languages area, but every one that i've used defines the behavior just fine. if instead the problem was if(1) if(some_condition) a = 1; ; else b = 1; then it's an entirely different flow of control in C (compared to the flow you posted), for instance.

Comment: The problem is that the indentation says one thing while the language says another.  It's a non-problem in C# because the editor will fix the indentation so that it matches the language's interpretation.

Comment: @Steven: I'm not a C# programmer and so I might be wrong but I wasn't aware there was one and only one editor. ;)

Comment: "C/C++ gets rid of the ambiguity by having a rule that says you can't have an if without an else as the body of an if." Of course you can. `if (a < b) if (c < d) a = b + d;`.

Comment: @Peter: I've rendered that statement infinitely more comprehensible by the insertion of several hyphens.  8-)

Comment: I think an easier way to explain the C/C++ rule is the usual one: `else` always binds to the closest matching `if`.

Comment: @Troubadour: There are as many editors as you like, but the default one is right in the IDE, and it fixes formatting. Notepad won't, but the various high-end replacement editors will

Answer (score 10):

Ambiguous else.

Some info here: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/yapps/yapps-doc/node3.html

But the classic example is:

```
if a then
  if b then
     x = 1;
  else 
     y = 1;
```

vs.

```
if a then
  if b then
     x = 1;
else 
  y = 1;
```

Comment: From the parser's point of view, the problem is that you can't resolve the ambiguity from the productions in language's grammar alone.  The parser needs extra information, specifically a rule saying how to resolve it.  (All the languages I know have a rule that says the else binds with the most recent if.)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this from a langauge design point of view.

The standard [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)-like grammar for `if`-`else`:

```
Statement :-   .. STUFF..
          |    IfStatement

IfStatement :- IF_TOKEN '(' BoolExpression ')' Statement IfElseOpt

IfElseOpt :-   /* Empty */
          |    ELSE_TOKEN Statement
```

Now from a parsers point of view:

```
if (cond1) Statement1
   if (cond2) Statement2
else Statement3
```

When you get to the ELSE_TOKEN the parser has two options, SHIFT or REDUCE. The problem is that which to choose requires another rule that the parser must follow. Most parsers generators default to SHIFT when given this option.

Comment: Except that C++ is usually not parsed with a shift-reduce (i.e. LR(k)) parser. ;)

Comment: Maybe not. But the __concept__ is the same and I did not want to discuss all the potential parsing schems as it did not really seem relavant.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the problem for Pascal?

This one is incorrectly indented.

```
if a then
  if b then
     x = 1;
  else
     y = 1;
```

Removing the semi-colon from after x = 1 would make it correctly indented.

This one correctly indented

```
if a then
  if b then
     x = 1;
else
  y = 1;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't Pascal have this problem? It has both compound blocks and non-compound blocks.

Comment: Most likely, Pascal defines a rule to resolve the ambiguity as most languages do, which isn't quite the same as not having the problem at all.

Comment: Is this Pascal? It should be x := 1, not x =1.